# What amount of zakat my family has to pay for our condition?

Tags: sharia, ramadan, zakat

My family Has taken a buy now pay later.
We have full amount to pay back but because of dynamic currency exchange rate we are waiting for right moment to pay back.
Also we have a loan form a friend we have not pay back yet. A large amount without it our family business will be effected
So what I want to ask is Did I have to pay zakat on amount of money we currently have or Minus the BNPL money And loan and pay zakat on remaining amount.??